# Replace text around two tags in python with regex

Tags: python, regex, replace, python-re

Given a string:

```
#symbol 1# / 7 - #symbol 2#
```

I want to return:

```
func('#symbol 1#') / 7 - func('#symbol 2#')
```

I've tried:

```
re.sub('[#*#]', 'func(\'', f2)
```

which gives:

```
func(symbol 1func( / 7 - func(symbol 2func(
```

where I don't want the `func('` for the second hash.

Is there a way to get the end of the hash replaced with `')` using the `re.sub`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
#[^\s#](?:[^#]*[^\s#])?#
```

Replace with `func('\g<0>')` where `\g<0>` refers to the whole match. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JiXOU6/1).

**Details**

- `#` - a `#` char
- `[^\s#]` - a char other than whitespace and `#`
- `(?:[^#]*[^\s#])?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `[^#]*` - 0 or more chars other than `#`
  - `[^\s#]` - a char other than whitespace and `#`
- `#` - a `#` char.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/S9TifP):

```
import re
text = '#symbol 1# / 7 - #symbol 2#'
print( re.sub(r'#[^\s#](?:[^#]*[^\s#])?#', r"func('\g<0>')", text) )
# => func('#symbol 1#') / 7 - func('#symbol 2#')
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for that. As a slight amendment how could I change this to handle spaces in the symbols:
'#symbol 1 like this# / 7 - #symbol 2 like that#'

Comment: @JDoe `#[\w\s]+#` or `#[^#]+#` or `#[^\s#](?:[^#]*[^\s#])?#`. It depends on what the rule for what can be in between the delimiting `#`s. Please add the requirement to the question, I will fix the regex accordingly.

Comment: Thank you - that saved me a lot of time!